# Problem with getting a name string from a query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm pretty new to rails and mongoid and I have a problem with extracting a string out of a query.

I have a class Filteroption

> class Fieldoption
>       include Mongoid::Document
>
> ```
> field :name, :type => String  
> field :option_id, :type => Integer
> ```
>
> end

and with this entries

```
 
+--------------------------+------------------------------------+-----------+  
| _id                      | name                               | option_id |  
+--------------------------+------------------------------------+-----------+  
| 4c6de6a11d41c86698000002 | Request URI                        | 1         |
| 4c6de6a11d41c86698000003 | Hostname                           | 4         |
```

When I query for the name with the option_id 4

> foobar = Fieldoption.only(:name).where(:option_id => '4')

foobar.name should be "Hostname". Instead I get

> foobar.name
>   => "Fieldoption"

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `name` method is already defined in Ruby to get the class name. You should rename your field to be able to get its content, or try `foobar.attributes["name"]`.

Comment: > foobar.attributes["name"]  
doesn't work.
Weired thing is that foobar.name works inside a scaffolded view for Fieldoption